# Fullscreen a video on OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, fullscreen

**--------------EDIT--------------**

I've simplified my original query as most people didn't understand.

**--------------EDIT--------------**

Hi, i want to display a video in fullscreen using OpenCV but am not sure how. This is my code so far, yes i am a novice, but you gotta start somewhere. I am running Python 3.6.3

**Question**: How do i show a video in fullscreen using OpenCV?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
cv2.namedWindow("window", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty("video.mp4",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
while(cap.isOpened()):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if ret == True:
    cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break
  else:
    break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I also get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/A/Desktop/vid.py", line 7, in 
>       cv2.setWindowProperty("video.mp4",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
>   cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp:443: error: (-27) NULL window in function cvSetModeWindow_W32

Comment: As for the first question, hit something else when you get frustrated (head against the wall is a popular choice). As for the error, note that the first parameter to [`cv2.setWindowProperty`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga66e4a6db4d4e06148bcdfe0d70a5df27) is "Name of the window.". Now, in the preceding statement you created a window named `"window"`, yet here you use a different name -- `"video.mp4"`. Also, further on, you have `cv2.imshow` using yet another window name -- `"Frame"`. The name is what's used to differentiate between multiple windows!

Comment: What do you mean by "display it for 30 seconds"? [`cv2.waitKey`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7) parameter is delay in milliseconds...

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/QpPuWein) works over here (I made some simlifications), but please clarify above, it could be interpreted in at least 3 different ways...

Comment: Unfortunately you are dealing with a complete and utter novice. I only recently starting getting into programming. I thought the `cv2.waitKey` was actually frames per second as when i decreased the value, the video would play slower. As for your code, it doesn't seem to work as nothing pops up when running. I am running Python 3.6.3 by the way.

Comment: OK :) For that first part -- get familiar with the documentation, and refer to it frequently. If nothing shows, maybe it has issues loading the video? Your script failed before you checked for that scenario. Try [this updated script](https://pastebin.com/nCuP1ZFW) which also prints out some debug messages to console.

Comment: Thank you Dan, that works like a charm!

Answer (score 12):

Thank to Dan Mašek, the answer to my original question is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

file_name = "video location here"
window_name = "window"
interframe_wait_ms = 30

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_name)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error: Could not open video.")
    exit()

cv2.namedWindow(window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty(window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

while (True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Reached end of video, exiting.")
        break

    cv2.imshow(window_name, frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(interframe_wait_ms) & 0x7F == ord('q'):
        print("Exit requested.")
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/nCuP1ZFW)

Answer (score 0):

```
while(cap.isOpened()):
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   if ret == True:
        cv2.namedWindow("window", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
        cv2.setWindowProperty("window",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,
               cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
        cv2.imshow('window',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
         break
```

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Answer (score -1):

I didnt understand your question but if u want to open video camera u can try this code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(src=frame, code=cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        out.write(gray)

        cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Friendly hint: Generally if you don't understand a question, it's a good idea to ask for clarification, rather than just post an answer based on a wild guess. Use a comment, downvote ("This question does not show any research effort; **it is unclear** or not useful") or flag as "should be closed ... unclear what you're asking" depending on severity.

Comment: Hi, sorry i should've made myself more clear. Ive updated my original post so that it contains useful information. As for your code, it does not apply to my needs. It works but it only inputs the webcam video, not an actual mp4 file.